# In the Reminders app on Mac, keyboard shortcut to finish editing the Notes field?

Tags: keyboard, reminders

In the Reminders app on Mac, when editing a value in the Notes field of an existing reminder item, what's the keyboard shortcut to commit (save) and finish editing the current note, while in the "details view" for that reminder item (as pictured here)?

[image]

What I've tried:

- <kbd>Return</kbd> - Inserts a newline.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> - Makes an error "beep" sound and does no other action. (Note remains in edit mode.)
- <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> - Inserts a newline.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> - Inserts a newline.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> - Inserts a newline.
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> - Exits edit mode, but *loses* changes made to the note value. (Like pressing a "Cancel" button, if there was one.)

Note: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> *does* work to commit the edit of a note when editing a reminder item in the "inline" view (in the middle pane pictured above). It doesn't work in the "details" (right) pane, though.

MacOS version: Ventura 13.3.1.

Comment: “Leave” the reminder you’re creating/editing. It autosaves

Comment: According to [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/reminders/keyboard-shortcuts-remn19b3424c/mac) Apple Support article, there's no shortcut(s) that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further experimentation (and inspired by @Allan's comment above!), I found a series of keystrokes that will work. After finishing keyboard text entry in the Notes field, with the Notes field still having the focus:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the focus to the reminder's Title field.
2. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to exit edit mode, committing the changes made in the reminder's detail view.
3. (Optional) Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the reminder's detail view.

Comment: Great work finding keyboard shortcuts to achieve this!